# How do LPC encoders work

Tags: audio, compression

I asked this question on the DSP forum and got a reasonable answer but the answer was very technical and was wondering whether someone could give me a more general idea of how it works.  My understanding of it is basically:

> LPC works by digitising the analog signal and splitting it into
> segments. For each of the segments we determine the key features of
> the signal and try to encode these as accurately as possible.
>
> The key
> features are the pitch of the signal (i.e. the basic formant
> frequency), the loudness of the signal and whether the sound is voiced
> or unvoiced. Parameters called vocal tract excitation parameters are
> also determined which are used in the vocal tract model to better
> model the state of the vocal tract which generated the sound.
>
> This
> data is passed over the network and decoded at the receiver. The pitch
> of the signal is used as input to either a voiced or unvoiced
> synthesiser, and the loudness data is used to boost the amplitude of
> this resulting signal. Finally the vocal cord model filters this sound
> by applying the LPC coefficients which were sent over the network.

What I'm finding hard to understand is the LPC coefficients - what exactly are they and what is going on with the linear predictive coding i.e. using the past samples etc.  Any help is much appreciated since I have an exam on this on tuesday!

Comment: for those who are also wondering what is LPC:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_predictive_coding